# Flash Builder 4.5.1 keyboard questions

Tags: flash, keyboard, builder, enter, onsubmit

just a quick question - most tablets and devices have a touchscreen keyboard that will allow the user to enter text. we've all seen them a million times.

How do I

- a) set the keyboard to a different type (say numeric)
- b) how do I change the "done" message to something else say in iOS when it's the
  ENTER key (i've noticed many apps that do that)
- c) how do I capture the "ondone" event or "onsubmit" event in Flash builder 4.5.1

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is implemented in Flashbuilder 4.6 through the softKeyboardType command:

```
<s:VGroup verticalAlign="middle">    
    <s:Label text="Soft Keyboard=Number"/>    
    <s:TextInput softKeyboardType="number" width="180"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

Here's a link to good article on it:
http://devgirl.org/2011/11/29/flex-mobile-development-flex-4-6-cool-new-soft-keyboard-features-sample-w-source/